# How to use .closest to toggle a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, closest

I'm trying to slidedown a paragraph using closest.  This is what I have so far.

JS

```
$(".info_btn").css("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out");

var info_btn_DEG = 0;

$(".info_btn").toggle(function() {
$(this).closest('p').slideDown("250");
info_btn_DEG += 45;
$(this).css("-webkit-transform", "rotateZ(" + info_btn_DEG + "deg)");
$(this).fadeTo("250", 0.65);
}, function() {

$(this).closest('p').slideDown("250");
info_btn_DEG += 45;
$(this).css("-webkit-transform", "rotateZ(" + info_btn_DEG + "deg)");
$(this).fadeTo("250", 0.3);
});
```

I also have this set up in a JSbin here for a complete look:

http://jsbin.com/atinap/7/edit

Comment: `.info_btn` doesn't have a ancestor element that match `p` and it is an img, therefore `$(this).closest('p')` will always return 0 elements. `.closest` only looks at ancestors and the current element.

Comment: FROM THE DOCUMENTATION: "For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree." The button has no ancestors of type 'p'

Comment: is there a way to get to <p class="description TXT_sm_blue">No description was available for this article.</p> through a jquery function to prompt the toggling?  There are several of them and so I was trying to do it relative to the button clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get to the "article_total" level (change that to a class, you should not have multiple identical IDs on one page) then from there you can target the p you need

the below code assumes you changed the id to class

```
$(this).closest('.article_wrapper').find('YOUR_ELEMENT_HERE');
```

Comment: mmm so I tried this and it doesn't slidedown $(this).closest('.article_total').find('.description').slideDown("250");  I made updates here http://jsbin.com/atinap/10/edit

Comment: my fault you should be targetting one level up "article_wrapper". This container has the p you need

Comment: YOU'RE THE MAN NOW DAWG!  Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: just make sure you do the same to the slide up